# Laravel multiple database connections with different servers

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 Laravel apps hosted on different servers,
App 1 is built with `Laravel 8` and app2 with `Laravel 9`, I want get/set data from app1 to app2

So I implemented multiple DB connection in app1 like this : 
databese.php

```
'mysql2' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST_SECOND', 'localhost'),
            'port'      => env('DB_PORT_SECOND', '3306'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE_SECOND', 'forge'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME_SECOND', 'forge'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD_SECOND',''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

.env :

```
DB_CONNECTION_SECOND=mysql
DB_HOST_SECOND=https://domain2.com
DB_PORT_SECOND=3306
DB_DATABASE_SECOND=db_name
DB_USERNAME_SECOND=db_username
DB_PASSWORD_SECOND="db_password" // I tried also without ""
```

`PurchaiseCode.php` model : this is the model which I will used to get/set data in app2 ( there is a table in DB app2 named purchaise_codes)

```
class PurchaiseCode extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $connection = 'mysql2';
    protected $table = 'purchaise_codes';

    protected $fillable = [
        'code',
        'name',
        'email',
    ];
}
```

**Issue**

`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused`  when I try to insert data to `purchaise_codes` table from app1
I tested the connection with a route :

```
Route::get('test/db', function() {
    $db = DB::connection('mysql2');
    return response()->json([
        'res' => $db->getPDO(),
    ]);
});
```

and I have this error also.

Comment: looks like you have a misconfiguration on your mysql on your server, make sure you are allowing external connections to your mysql.

Comment: @didenetahi I fixed it by edit db host to localhost, but now I have this error : `SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db_name.purchaise_codes' doesn't exist` , I try wtih another table name it works but when the table name has underscore it doesn't work !